# Conditional dataframe slicing

Tags: r

I would like to remove the rows of this dataframe in which, if the pattern `,2)` exists, it just exist in one of the columns.

As an example: in this dataframe, each column is a character class (representing a vector in each position):

```
A   c(0,1)  c(1,1)
B   c(0,2)  c(0,1)
C   c(1,1)  c(0,1)
D   c(1,2)  c(0,2)
```

I would like to subset it, removing row B, as the pattern is present in one of the columns but not in the other.

I tried to use `grep`, but I don't know how to specify the conditional statement.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single column we would do this (calling your data `d`)

```
d[!grepl(",2)", d$column_name, fixed = TRUE), ]
```

But we need to check all the columns and find rows that have exactly one match. For this, we'll convert to `matrix` and use `rowSums` to count the matches by row:

```
n_occurrences = rowSums(matrix(grepl(",2)", as.matrix(d), fixed = TRUE), nrow = nrow(d)))
d[n_occurrences != 1, ]
#   V1     V2     V3
# 1  A c(0,1) c(1,1)
# 3  C c(1,1) c(0,1)
# 4  D c(1,2) c(0,2)
```

---

Using this sample data:

```
d = read.table(text = 'A   c(0,1)  c(1,1)
B   c(0,2)  c(0,1)
C   c(1,1)  c(0,1)
D   c(1,2)  c(0,2)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as the selected answer above, but you can also split into two variables at the blank space and then create separate indices.

```r
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(v1=c('c(0,1)  c(1,1)','c(0,2)  c(0,1)',
                'c(1,1)  c(0,1)','c(1,2)  c(0,2)'))

empty_omit <- function(vec) vec[vec!='']
get_even <- function(vec) vec[seq_along(vec) %% 2 == 0]
get_odd <- function(vec) vec[seq_along(vec) %% 2 ==1]

df$v2 = strsplit(df$v1, ' ') %>% unlist() %>% empty_omit %>% get_odd()
df$v3 = strsplit(df$v1, ' ') %>% unlist() %>% empty_omit %>% get_even()

idx_v2 = grepl(",2)", df$v2)
idx_v3 = grepl(",2)", df$v3)

df[!idx_v2 | idx_v3, ]
```